# Scala Single Abstract Method & Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, single-abstract-method

I'm just getting use to Scala Single Abstract Method which I did not know well, until I went through several blogs on Type Class.

I am able after few minutes to figure out what's going on when I see it. I wonder if there is a way in Intellij to Highlight SAM, so it is easy to recognize.

I mean this kind of things made me think twice

```
 @inline final def instance[A](f: JsValue => Either[String, A]): JsDecoder[A] = f(_)
```

Comment: `f(_)` is redundant, doesn't it work with just `f`?

Comment: Not my code. Comes from FP mortals with cats ` https://github.com/turt13/fpmortals-cats/blob/publish/example/src/main/scala/fpmortals/jsonformat/JsDecoder.scala `

Comment: Ah it seems it doesn't work with just `f` apparently **SAM** requires an explicit lambda signature.

Comment: Well, that’s something to further keep in mind :) Thanks for the tip. I guess I will just get use to recognize them with practice

Comment: Well, when you have a type class that is not a SAM you normally define `instance` (constructor) method by default. So when you don't have to, this means it was a SAM.

Comment: Surely you can define your Wartremover/Scalafix rule for that.

Comment: That's the reason why I defined `@com.github.dmytromitin.auxify.macros.instance`.